# how to classify input text under different categories

Tags: r, text-classification

text= "my dog is a rice eater", "I want to buy an a new","my cat prefers chocolate milk"

how could I extract keywords from these text (or text corpora) and classify them in different categories (i.e. dog, cat be categorized as Pet and rice, chocolate milk be categorized as Food)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were down voted because the question does not provide enough detail as to what you mean by "classify" and because you did not show what target outcome you wish to achieve.

Here's a basic answer, however: You can create a dictionary and count the hits according to the dictionary.  In **quanteda**, it works like this:

```
text <- c("my dog is a rice eater", 
          "I want to buy an a new",
          "my cat prefers chocolate milk")

library("quanteda")

fooddict <- dictionary(list(pet = c("cat", "dog"),
                            food = c("rice", "chocolate milk")))

dfm(text, dictionary = fooddict)
# Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 2 features (33.3% sparse).
# 3 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#        features
# docs    pet food
#   text1   1    1
#   text2   0    0
#   text3   1    1
```

Comment: ,i am using Text2Vec r package & using "movie_review" data for practice; after creating vocabulary there around 80k words, i want to insert all this words into different categories; this classification/categorization could be on the basis of probability or any suitable process which will produce more accurate output